# Adding logging functionallity in package

Tags: packages, options

I build a package with code to solve specific equations. The code has become quite complex and so to convince myself (and others) that it works correctly I would like to add some code to write messages to a log file. The messages would depend on the specific function for which I want information and I want to be able to turn logging on or off for certain functions (not all functions need to write to a log file though, only the 'big' ones).

So basically how could one alter the code in a package such that:

1. the user of the package has the option to turn on logging for certain functions, and
2. the code itself needs as little altering as possible. In particular I want to be able to add functions and test them without having to rewrite other functions their logging behaviour.

---

Some of the solutions I thought about are the following

1. Use `OptionsPattern[]` in every function to start logging. Problem is that I have to alter the code of each function and put `If` statements everywhere which messes up readability.
2. Implement a function `PrintLog[file_]`, that takes a function and tells it to evaluate and write info to log file. Then there would be some construction in the functions themselves that get turned on by the `PrintLog` function. At the moment I wouldn't know how to implement this solution though...

Comment: I would try a combination of `EchoFunction` with `ToString` and function that writes into a file like `WriteString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common way is to use an inert symbol for the "logging function", and assign a value to this function on demand.

Example:

```
f[x_] := 
  Module[{y = x^2},
    myPrint["Input is ", x];
    y
  ]
```

Then you can use `Block[{myPrint = Print}, f[5]]` to temporarily activate logging.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that the "inert" function still evaluates its arguments and may have side effects. E.g., `Module[{},myPrint[FiniteGroupData["S30", "CycleIndex"][[1]]//Length];];//Timing` yields non-zero time `{0.171875, Null}`. A solution I used to is to `SetAttributes[myPrint, HoldAll];`; in this case, `Block` will temporarily redefine the function along with its attributes and the kitchen sink, so in your example using a `Block` this `HoldAll` will be ignored. Just double checked; the `Print` prints '5604' which is about the right monomial count, I guess, give or take. :)